# How I can get the index of class(css) array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the index,
`document.getElementsByClassName("selected")[i].css("background-color", "green");` is not working

```js
$(function(){
    $("#but").click(function () {
        var corr = $(".lblcorrectans");
        var selected = $(".selected");

        for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
            if (corr[i].innerHTML == selected[i].innerHTML) {
                document.getElementsByClassName("selected")[i].css("background-color", "green");
            }
            else {
                document.getElementsByClassName("selected")[i].css("background-color", "red");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is model, eg model.length?

Comment: that means that item does not exist

Comment: This looks way too complicated. Can you include all the relevant code and markup?

Comment: @Elvin You can accept my answer if it solved your problem

Comment: @Argee sorry ..i forgot write this [model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))] ....

Comment: @BasheerKharoti thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will return a list of `Html Collection` and you can access a specific element via index if it exists in the `Collection`.

**[NOTE]**
However, you are using `css` function of the `jQuery` with `Html Element` which actually does not exist. Here's how you should do that with `Jquery`. You basically need to use the [EQ](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) API of the Jquery

```js
$('.para').eq(0).css({'background-color': 'red'}) // eq(i) or whatever the index is
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="para">First Para</p>
<p class="para">Second Para</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just iterate with `forEach`?

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('selected')).forEach(e => {
  e.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

Comment: OP is already using jQuery. Why so complicated? What is HTMLElement#css()?